# Нахождение корней уравнения методом хорд

Tags: python

Очень нужен пример кода <Нахождение корней уравнения методом хорд>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уравнение: x<sup>3</sup>-4.4*x<sup>2</sup>+28.6*x - 42 = 0;
на отрезке [1;2] и точность e = 0.0005.

```
import math

def F(x):
    return 0.1 * math.pow(x, 2) - x * math.log(x)

def F1(x):
    res=0.2 * x - math.log(x) - 1
    print(res)
    return res

def Method(a, b):
    try:
        x0 = (a + b) / 2
        xn = F(x0)
        xn1 = xn - F(xn) / F1(xn)
        while abs(xn1 - xn) > math.pow(10, -5):
            xn = xn1  # вот так надо было
            xn1 = xn - F(xn) / F1(xn)
        print(xn1)
        return xn1
    except ValueError:
        print("Value not invalidate")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=float(input())
    a=float(input())
    b=float(input())
    F(x)
    F1(x)
    Method(a, b)
```